# Pass DeviceIoControl input buffer with DirectIO

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, system

I know that we can get output buffer using MDL from driver using IOCTL with METHOD_IN_DIRECT.But it is possible to pass input buffer with METHOD_IN_DIRECT/METHOD_OUT_DIRECT.I found on [OSR](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=92)  that METHOD_IN_DIRECT/METHOD_OUT_DIRECT is only applicable on output buffer.Why input is buffered IO always Direct IO.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You can use the second buffer for direct input (METHOD_IN_DIRECT) or direct output (METHOD_OUT_DIRECT).  METHOD_IN_DIRECT is appropriate if you're going to process a large amount of data provided by the user, particularly via DMA or PIO.  In this case the first buffer might be unused, or it might contain control data that tells the driver what to do with the data in the second buffer.

Comment: So I keep it simple that DeviceIoControl can get output buffer with  METHOD_IN_DIRECT/METHOD_OUT_DIRECT...But the the input buffer will be always processed with Buffered IO.So is it possible to pass input buffer with DirectIO.

Comment: Yes, if you use METHOD_IN_DIRECT then the second buffer (the "output" buffer) is *actually* an input buffer.

Comment: ... but there is no way for *both* buffers to be Direct IO.

Comment: @HarryJohnston
Can you tell me good resource where i can understand this in better way..I am not getting you "the second buffer (the "output" buffer) is actually an input buffer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the control code is defined with METHOD_IN_DIRECT, then DeviceIoControl has the following signature:

```
BOOL WINAPI DeviceIoControl(
  _In_         HANDLE hDevice,
  _In_         DWORD dwIoControlCode,
  _In_opt_     LPVOID lpInBuffer1,
  _In_         DWORD nInBuffer1Size,
  _In_opt_     LPVOID lpInBuffer2,
  _In_         DWORD nInBuffer2Size,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpBytesReturned,
  _Inout_opt_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

Note that there are two input buffers (both containing data for the device driver to read) and no output buffers (so the device driver cannot return any data to user mode).

The first input buffer, `lpInBuffer1`, is copied to a system buffer, so it should be relatively small.  If the control code doesn't need two input buffers, `lpInBuffer1` will be `NULL`.

The second input buffer, `lpInBuffer2`, is made available to the device driver via Direct IO, so is suitable for large buffers and/or for use with DMA or PIO.

It should be noted that Windows does not appear to include any drivers that use METHOD_IN_DIRECT for control codes accessible to user mode.  (It is used in some control codes passed between drivers.)  However, it is possible for third-party device drivers to provide a control code that uses this method.

Comment: Does the caller have to pin the second buffer to memory?

Comment: @ShuhengZheng, no, the operating system locks the second buffer in memory.  (As always, the caller mustn't release the memory allocation or read or modify the contents of the buffer while the call is in progress, so if you're using a managed language like .NET you may need to take steps to prevent the runtime from messing with the buffer, but you don't need to call VirtualLock or anything.)

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to release the memory allocation while it is locked though?

Comment: @ShuhengZheng, there's no guarantee that I can find in the documentation that an attempt to free locked pages will fail cleanly.  It won't crash the operating system, but it might crash the process.